# Call Class by String c#

Tags: c#, string, class

This question has already been answered sometime, but for me it's still not clear enough.

So issue is: classname is stored in a string, this needs to be used to call a class like this:

```
Jobs TheClass = new Jobs();
```

Instead of Jobs there should be the String.
After that, this function takes a list stored in that class.

```
RefList = new List<string>(TheClass.ListItems);
```

The most answers come up with this code:

```
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Jobs"));
```

But I still don't know how to implement it in my code

I've tried this:

```
dynamic adap = System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(StringJobs));

RefList = new List<string>(adap.listitems);
```

It gives me a error: Value cannot be null. I think it doesn't properly detect "Jobs" as a class. Also when I change StringJobs to Jobs, which is exactly the class name, it doesn't work.
Sorry for dubble posting questions, I don't have enough reputation to post comments on answers so I can't ask it that way.

Comment: I direct you to this duplicate. It shows how to work with this API. If you cannot figure out how to use it ask about a specific problem instead of posting an exact duplicate.

Comment: thanks, I missed that question!

Comment: What are the values of `StringJobs` and of `adap`?

Comment: `StringJobs` is for instance "Accountent". `adap` I don't know, but i solved my problem by using the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to know anything about the type, you have to use dynamic.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ObjectHandle handleA = Activator.CreateInstance("ConsoleApplication2", "ConsoleApplication2.A");
            dynamic instanceA = handleA.Unwrap();
            instanceA.A1 = 1;
            instanceA.b1 = "11";
            Console.WriteLine(instanceA.A1);
            Console.WriteLine(instanceA.b1);
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public int A1 { get; set; }
        public string b1 { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! The duplicated question didn't help, this did.